# Sort Cells by Using NSDictionaries from an NSMutableArray

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, cells

I have NSDictionaries stored in an NSMutableArray. Each NSDictionary has a NSNumber inside of it. So right now, my tableview will show the cells in the way they are ordered in the array. What I want to do is reorder the cells from highest NSNumber to lowest NSNumber, so how would I do this with all the NSDictionaries in the NSMutableArray. I will probably need a for loop or something like that but I am not sure how to do it.

Also I have NSDate's (non-formatted) in my NSDictionaries, so how would I sort the NSDictionaries based upon the newest dates inside them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `sortedArrayUsingSelector` method of NSMutableArray and provide a sorting function, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *yourSortedArray;
yourSortedArray = [originalArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(yourCompareFunction:)];

...

- (NSComparisonResult)yourCompareFunction:(NSDictionary *)otherObject {
   return [[self objectForKey:@"number_key"] compare:[otherObject objectForKey:@"number_key"]];
}
```

I didn't tested this but that's the idea.